# AWS S3: Directory access is forbidden

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using this `PHP` library to upload file on AWS-S3.

https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

```
$this->load->library('aws/s3');
S3::setAuth('xxxxx', 'yyyyy');
S3::putObject(S3::inputFile(APPPATH.'index.html'),
                   'test_con',
                   time().'.html',
                   S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
                   array(),
                   array(),
                   S3::STORAGE_CLASS_STANDARD
                   );
```

As you can see, I am using `public-read`. But, in AWS console I am not able to download / view that file. Error: `Directory access is forbidden.`

Strange case: If I use `text(e.g.: xyz)` instead of this line: `S3::inputFile(APPPATH.'index.html')`. Then I can access that file.

**Output:**

```
$d = S3::getObject('test_con', '1471467180.html');
print_r($d);

stdClass Object ( [error] => [body] =>

Directory access is forbidden.
[headers] => Array ( [date] => 1471533372 [time] => 1471467193 [hash] => 6b37305eedfsdf3234242431bfsffd5dfd3bb1 [type] => text/html [size] => 123 ) [code] => 200 )
```

Comment: Make sure your [bucket permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html) are set up!

Comment: Bucket and link both are public.

Comment: Add the command you use to download the file and the full error text seen.

Comment: @ShankarPS: I am trying to access it directly from browser as it's public URL.

Comment: @ShankarPS: Please check updated question.